# flatten annotation

Tags: itext

Here what I need to achieve.

I received some pdf from my customers, some contains stamp, note etc... inside the pdf.

So I need to flatten those annotations so they become part of the pdf.

I know you can flatten the form field using itextSharp but you cannot directly flatten the annotation.

Someone told me to achieve this I need to o add the appearance of the annotation to the content stream, for instance with PdfStamper, and then throw away the annotation.

Someone have a clue of to achieve this it will be nice.

Thank you